# Utility/product to subset large database into small one for QA needs?

Tags: mysql, subset

Does some know of good utility/product helping to subset large MySQL database into small one for QA needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump allows you to supply a `where` clause. You can then set a limit eg :-

mysqldump --where="true LIMIT 100" dbname > dump.sql

NB: I've not tested this code.

Comment: how can i do this in phpmyadmin